# Sharable link for individual jQuery bPopup on page?

Tags: jquery, bpopup

I'm using bpopup on a single page to display people's profile (due to this I won't be able to put the link)

and each item has unique ID with separate code attached.

Will it be possible to share specific user's popup as individual url

e.g. www.domain.com/profile#user-3146374

then when people click the link, the page opens up and bpopup initiates automatically

```
<a href="#" id="button-3146374">
<div class="image">Image goes here</div>
</a>

<div class="driver-profile" id="user-3146374" style="display:none;">
-- pop up content --
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#button-3146374').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#user-3146374').bPopup();
     });
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably either need to populate the HTML with the profile when the profile is rendered and then use an inline script to pop open the modal or by using an AJAX call to fetch the data from the server and then open the modal